# Which wood turns grey, and which turns black with time?

Tags: wood, woodworking

There are types of wood that turn grey with time, and others that turn almost black. At least, unfinished wood changes color rather quickly.

The question is which turn grey, and which turn black?

It is to build a tiny house. Most Swiss chalets turn black with time and I wouldn't want that.

Comment: The question is quite broad as it is. You're basically asking us to chart the hundreds of species for you. Better, describe what you're doing and what species you're considering.

Comment: Both redwood and cedar turn gray with time and both are good for exterior work. As far as black I am not sure of that.

Comment: Also consider a good stain to get a color you'd like, and protect it (need the right type of stain, maybe a sealer - I'm not an expert on this but that's the general idea) at the same time.

Comment: i just watched a youtube the other day that talks about the characteristics of different wood from alder to zebrawood. i don't have a link, but there's several on there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t want to leave the wood unstained. When wood weathers “naturally”, it will be 1) uneven and 2) blotchy.

1) Siding under an overhang will remain its natural color while siding with direct exposure to the sun and elements will fade quickly.

2) Wood will fade and weather differently based on where each piece is cut from the tree.

Most paint manufacturers make a “weathering” stain. It helps all siding to quickly weather uniformly.

Wood should not be left untreated. Even wood siding near the ground will have water (and dirt) splash up on it and stain it.

BTW, we use Western Red Cedar, White Cedar, or Redwood for siding. You can order it with 3 sides surfaced and the face “rough-sawn”. It comes in shiplap, bevel, and board and batt.

Any wood left to the weather long enough, will eventually turn black without some protection (stain).

Comment: Do you mean that no wood stays gray, and that they all turn black in time?

Comment: @TenzinDorje Yes. Weathering isn’t just from sun fading. Dirt, mold, etc. will get in the pours of the wood and eventually turn the wood black.